# Change Resources in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to do a web calendar with multiple options for views.
I have a Students view and a Project views (both timeline views in FullCalendar, where Students and Projects are resources).

The problem is I don't know how to change the resources dinamically. I've tried this:

```
var resources = 'students';
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    resources: {
        url: 'resource-load.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'data': resources
        }
    }
});
```

And when I change views:

```
switch (selected) {
case 'general':
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'month');
    break;
case 'students':
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'timelineDay');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option','resourceLabelText','Students');
    resources = 'students';
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');
    break;
case 'proyects':
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'changeView', 'timelineDay');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option','resourceLabelText','Proyects');
    resources = 'proyects';
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');
    break;
default: break;
}
```

It loads the students correctly but it doesn't change the resources when I change views.
Also I tried using [resources as a function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/resources_function/) but I don't really know how to make that works.

Now I have this:

```
var resources = 'students';
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    resources: function(callback) {
        getResources(function(resourceObjects) {
            callback(resourceObjects);
        });
    }
});
```

And a function:

```
function getResources(handleData) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"resource-load.php",
        data: {
            'data': resources
        },
        success:function(data) {
            handleData(data); 
        }
    });
}
```

And the other events as before.
But now it doesn't even load the events.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/addResource/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/removeResource/ will probably help you. What you're doing now e.g. `resources = 'students';` is meaningless. `resources` is just a variable on its own and is nothing to do with fullCalendar. I think you are imagining it will affect `        data: {
            'data': resources
        }`, but fullCalendar has already run that code previously, and used the value of `resources` as it was in that moment. It does not run that code again or take the new value of `resources` ever.

Comment: Alternatively, if you just want to be able to pass a dynamic value for "data" into the server each time you fetch the resources, try implementing it as per this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/resources_function/ . Then you can dynamically pass whatever values you want to the server as well as what fullCalendar provides.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use the resource as a function method, but I don't understand how to implement it, I don't know how that works.

Comment: you define a function as per the example. Then within it you make your own ajax call to your URL to get the resource data. The advantage is you can pass extra parameters to it, such as your resource variable (if it's set somewhere else, which it looks like it is, make sure its a global variable). Then you pass the values back to fullCalendar via the "callback" function, exactly as shown in the example. It's all there demonstrated for you in the documentation. If you try it and can't make it work, update the question here with your new code and any errors you get, and we can take a look.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try!

Comment: I've updated the code, and I'm pretty sure that I did it wrong. Sorry, but I'm a noob :(

Comment: No need for the inner "getResources" function really, you're just nesting another named function inside the anonymous function. That in itself isn't the cause of a problem though, just a minor inefficiency. If it doesn't load anything, then probably there's some sort of error somehow. Do you know how to use your browser's developer tools (console and network tabs) to check for code errors and ajax errors?

Comment: One thing I can spot just looking at the code is: in your original definition, the call to resource-load was made using a POST, but in your new code it's a GET ($.ajax uses GET unless you specify otherwise). You need to set the `method: "POST"` option in the $.ajax options. You possibly also need to set `dataType: "json"` as well, to be sure that jQuery interprets the returned data as a JSON object and not just a string.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will change it and test.

Comment: It was that! I changed the method to POST and data type json, and it worked! Thanks a lot for your help!
Should I edit the question to show the answer?

Comment: No problem, happy to help :-). If I write the various bits from the comments up into an answer, would you be ok to mark it as the accepted answer? That's the correct way rather than editing it into the question.

Comment: Yes, of course, thanks a lot!

Comment: that's done now. Good luck with the rest of your project.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing in your first example e.g. `resources = 'students';` is essentially meaningless. `resources` is just a variable on its own and is nothing to do with fullCalendar.

I think you are imagining it will affect `data: { 'data': resources }`, but fullCalendar has already run that code previously, and used the value of `resources` as it was in that moment. It does not run that code again or take the new value of the `resources` variable ever.

If you just want to be able to pass a dynamic value for "data" into the server each time you fetch the resources, you need to implement your "resources" fullCalendar option as a custom function as per this documentation: fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/resources_function . Then you can pass whatever values you want to the server as well as what fullCalendar provides.

Your second code example does exactly that, following what I wrote in the comments. The only issue with it is that the ajax call definition is wrong, based on your earlier example. You need to override some defaults, and set the following additional fields in the `$.ajax` options:

```
method: "POST"
```

and

```
dataType: "json"
```

(In the first example, fullCalendar had silently set the dataType for you, but now you're doing a custom version so you have to do it yourself, and you also just forgot to set the HTTP method again.)